# How to move data from a DB in one syabse server to another db in different sybase server?

Tags: sybase

I want to move the data from a DB to another DB where the two DB's are in two different Sybase servers.
I have tried

```
"INSERT INTO <target_table_name>
   LOCATION target_server.target_database
   SELECT FROM (source table or query);"
```

I have executed the above statements from the source Sybase server in RapidSQL tool but it is throwing an error "Incorrect Syntax near LOCATION".

Thanks

Comment: try `BCP` utility instead

Answer (score 0):

You could use "Component Integration Services".  A table on another Sybase server is made to appear locally, as if it were a local table.
You (or the DBA) has to set up Component Integration Services and then set up the table (as a proxy table.)
If you just need the table to be copied over occasionally Meet is right - bulk copy with bcp is the thing.  Look that up in the Sybase Utilities guide.